# Bootstrap working on chrome but not on firefox?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Hello I am building a website for a friend and the site looks good on chrome but when I try to test it for firefox it looks nothing like the chrome version. Looking at the debugger for firefox it seems like the bootstrap css is not loading from the CDN. Any tips would be appreciated! Here is the part of my code that calls the bootstrap CDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/edr3ydd.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\about.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>About</title>
 </head>
<body>
```

Comment: Check the network console or eventually a firefox extension that can block the script loading

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to never use CDN when developing websites or applications for other people. CDNs are great to bootstrap the layout when you are doind something by yourself as a draft.

But when it comes to distribution for third people I suggest you to download bootstrap package and use it on the local server where the HTML page is.

Comment: its funny how often I see people espousing that opinion, yet how many top tier sites do not follow it. This one, for example.

Comment: Bootstrap wasn't loading in FireFox until I used a local copy of the css and js files. Seems to work fine now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Just to test this, download a copy and serve your CSS files locally. Firefox might be blocking your asset requests. Check for console error messages in firefox.