# Bootstrap doesn't work on normal Firefox tab on android

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap, I currently have this https://alternativeliferp.com/ which works fine on desktop browsers and most mobile browsers, but I found that it doesn't work on normal tabs of Firefox on my mobile. It completely messes up there. Strangely, it seems to work fine on privacy tabs in Firefox. I looked for people with similiar problems and tried some solutions but none have worked.

Here are some screenshots

Normal tab:

[image]

Privacy tab:

[image]

Here is the code:
[GitHub](https://github.com/BronzeCheese/alrpBootstrapTheme)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34651179/10544328) from another question. All I had to do was to host bootstrap myself. Kind of strange it worked fine on privacy tabs of Firefox, though.